# Order by date (varchar)?

Tags: mysql

I want to order by date.

e.g.

```
table_date
February 2011
January 2011
December 2010
```

I've already tried:

```
SELECT distinct(table_date) FROM tables ORDER BY table_date DESC
```

bur it doesn't work.

I get this instead:

```
January 2011
February 2011
December 2010
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Tried reformatting the order by with DATE_FORMAT? This might get the query to handle the order by as a date instead of a string. Haven't tested it though so not 100% sure it will solve it

Comment: If table_date is a varchar, the order by will order alphabetically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to order by date, *store it as a date, not a string.* Unless your date string is of the form `yyyy-mm-dd`, it will not sort as you want it.

Databases are hard enough work as-is, without people making it harder, and you should be striving as much as possible to avoid what I like to call *SQL gymnastics.*

Store it as a date then, if you must, use date functions to get it in the form `February 2011`.

It'll be a lot easier going that way than what you're trying to do.

---

Even if you *can't* change any of the current columns due to code restrictions, you can always add another column to the database like `TABLE_DATE_AS_DATE` and put in an insert/update trigger to populate it based on `TABLE-DATE`.

Then just do:

```
update table x set table_date = table_date
```

or something similar, to fire the trigger for all rows.

Then, your query can still get at `table_date` but use `table_date_as_date` for ordering. That's a kludge of course but I've had to use tricks like that in the past when it was imperative the code could not change, so we had to resort to DBMS trickery.

Comment: And not only easier, also faster. Much faster.

Answer (score 14):

If you must store the dates in a `varchar` which as others pointed out is not recommended, you could use:

```
SELECT table_date FROM tables ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(table_date, '%M %Y') DESC;
```

Answer (score 6):

Store dates as [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), not as VARCHAR, that's a huge mistake. Use [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your content. When you're done, you can order by dates without any problems.

Answer (score 6):

Date should be stored as date and not `VARCHAR.`

Suppose you have `table_date` in the following format `(DD-MM-YYYY)`

```
table_date  
2011-01-01 
2011-02-01   
2010-12-01
```

Now you can perform order by clause in the following way

```
SELECT * FROM table_order ORDER BY str_to_date(date, "%Y-%M-%D") ASC
```

I doubt if the output will be in ordered form

Comment: This will be very slow on larger tables, an index on the date can't be used. The real problem is the datatype, that's the problem that the OP has to solve.

Comment: Create a new column using DATE as datatype, update all records using the old content and str_to_date(), test the result, drop the old column. VARCHAR is useless for dates.