# order by in select statement sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

I try to fetch date from table in descending order but when i write order by clause in query this shows date in ascending order .. i can not post whole query i post specific line e.g. order by .. when i tried this is what query shows

```
 date
    01/03/2016
    26/02/2016
    25/02/2016
    06/01/2015
```

but this is what i want in re

```
 date
    06/01/2015
   25/02/2016
    26/02/2016
    01/03/2016
```

this is what i tried

```
 ORDER BY
convert(date, account.postdate) DESC,      
account.ACDOCNO ASC
```

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your date in ORDER BY from DESC to ASC

```
ORDER BY
convert(date, account.postdate) ASC,   
account.ACDOCNO ASC
```

or simply

```
ORDER BY
convert(date, account.postdate) ,   
account.ACDOCNO
```

As ASC is the default sorting order in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here may be a language problem - the desired output you've shared is indeed in **ascending** order (which for dates means older to newer). So just use `asc` instead of `desc` and you should be OK:

```
ORDER BY
convert(date, account.postdate) ASC, -- Here!
account.ACDOCNO ASC
```

Comment: but asc means higher to lower

Comment: @Bakhtawar no, that's where your mistake it. `asc` (short for ascending) means lower to higher

Comment: @Bakhtawar to quote [SQL Server's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) - "ASC sorts from the lowest value to highest value. DESC sorts from highest value to lowest value."

Comment: i have a amount column  when i put this line convert(date, account.postdate) ASC, in query then amount value change when i erase these values in query then correct amount is displayed but when i put these lines amount is changed ... why is this occur?

Comment: when i write this ORDER BY
    account.ACDOCNO ASC,    
 convert(date, account.postdate) ASC date not order by  as asc.. when i write convert line above account.acdocno dates and amount changes..

Answer (score 0):

It also depends how you save the dates in the table. Do you save them as type DATETIME?

If not here is a related post:
[Order by date (varchar)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080375/order-by-date-varchar)

By the way, what is the `convert()` doing here? From what I've checked in the reference its used for converting string into different character sets.