# Convert INT (date and time) to date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using the old wrong way for dates, and im unable to change it because it will take a lot of time and effort, not to mention a lot of crashes.

I have the following design:

1. match_day : 31
2. match_month : 12
3. match_year : 2016
4. time: 23:15

And comparing in the normal way `ORDER BY (...etc)` won't work here, and i see that i need to convert it to time, but the thing is these are INT not string, but i've tried to use the following query:

```
SELECT match_day,match_month,match_year,time, STR_TO_DATE(match_day+'-'+match_month+'-'+match_year+'-'+time, '%e %c %Y %H:%i') AS date FROM SoccerMatches ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(match_day+'-'+match_month+'-'+match_year+'-'+time, '%e-%c-%Y-%H:%i') DESC;
```

`data` is NULL, and i don't think it will work because these are INT and i guess we can't use `'-'` in queries.

this query:

```
SELECT match_day,match_month,match_year,time FROM SoccerMatches
```

result:

`30 | 12 | 2016 | 23:15`

Query im using and its showing false results:

```
  Select t.*,plan_b.value From SoccerMatches t, plan_b Order by (t.match_year AND t.match_month AND t.match_day) DESC;
```

Any ideas how to make it work / beside creating a new column for it, i want a workaround.

Comment: Already checked this: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080375/order-by-date-varchar

Comment: Why doesn't `str_to_date` work for you?

Comment: You can easily order them as they are. Why can't you?

Comment: I would use PHP to convert it.

Comment: Its not a correct order, and im already using php, these queries are using in an API.

Comment: I've added the query im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use + (is for sqlserver) in mysql you can use concat

```
SELECT 
 match_day
,match_month
,match_year
,time
, STR_TO_DATE(concat( match_day, '-', match_month ,'-',match_year,'-',time), 
    '%e %c %Y %H:%i') AS date 
FROM SoccerMatches ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Comment: `date` is still null in the result when i executed this query.

Comment: You have `-` between the parts of the date in `concat()`, but the format string has spaces.

Comment: BTW, if you're concatenating a bunch of variables with the same separator, you can use `CONCAT_WS()` to give the separator once.