# date wise sort in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

example:

```
sh_date
30.11.2017
01.01.2018
31.12.2017
```

i want like this:

```
sh_date
30.11.2017
31.12.2017
01.01.2018
```

Comment: Hint:  `order by`.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: structure: varchar

Comment: Switch to `date` type instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the date is varchar

you can try bellow one in mysql

```
SELECT sh_date
FROM table_name
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(sh_date ,'.',',') ,'%d,%m,%Y') ASC
```

Need to convert string to date before sorting

```
For eg:30.11.2017 it will convert to date
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('30.11.2017' ,'.',',') ,'%d,%m,%Y')

Output
2017-11-30
```

please add if anything is missing

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
select sh_date from table_name order by sh_date ASC
```

sh_date is a char or varchar and not a date otherwise your order by clause would be fine.

```
SELECT sh_date  
FROM 
     table_name
ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(sh_date , EventDate,101)  ASC
```

Comment: nah. date wise is not coming

Comment: which data type you use for date in db

Comment: varchar data type

Answer (score 0):

you will have to convert it to datetime and then you can order:

```
select sh_date
from table_name
order by convert(datetime, sh_date, 103) ASC
```

for further study : please go to this thread [Order by date (varchar)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080375/order-by-date-varchar)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`sh_date`, 103) ASC
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3

Comment: select [sh_date]
from table_name order by    cast([sh_date] as datetime) asc

Comment: edited my question. gave a link in the below part.. hope it will help you to figure out..