# PHP Date stored in VARCHAR in format DD/MM/YYYY needs to be sorted in ASC ORDER in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

as the title suggests the date format in the database in a table is stored as DD/MM/YYYY format in VARCHAR (with slashes). I want to sort the results in ascending order only. But my query is not allowing me to do so. A simple `ORDER by order_date ASC` does not work. The developer who did this before made this mistake of not inserting it in DATE format. Now the problem is that it has thousands of records which cannot be edited now one by one. I therefore need to have a solution to display it in ascending order by writing a PHP function. But I do not know how to. Can anybody please help?

SQL

```
<?php

                $this->db->select('str_to_date(your_col, '%d/%m/%Y') as my_date');
                $this->db->order_by('my_date','ASC');
                $this->db->where('customer_id',$id);
                $qry3 = $this->db->get('due');

                    foreach ($qry3->result() as $row){

                $total=$total+ ($row->due-$row->paid_amount);
                $total=$total-$row->discount_allowed;
                $total=$total+$row->credit_note_amount;
                ?>


                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row->my_date?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->order_no?></td>
                        <td>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($row->due)) {
                           echo "SALE A/C";
                        } else if (isset($row->particulars)) {
                          echo $row->particulars;
                        } else {
                            echo $row->particulars;
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>
                        <td align="">
                        <?php if (isset($row->due))
                            {
                            echo $row->due;
                            } else {
                                echo $row->credit_note_amount;
                            }
                        ?>
                         </td>
                        <td align="">
                        <?php

                        if (isset($row->paid_amount)) {
                          echo $row->paid_amount;
                        } else if (isset($row->discount_allowed)) {
                            echo $row->discount_allowed;
                        } else {

                        }
                         ?> </td>
                        <td class="info"><?php echo $total?></td>



                    </tr>

                    <?php }?>
```

Comment: saving date in `varchar` format is wrong table structure design. Use `timestamp`,'date',`date-time` type . It will make your query processing easy

Comment: @AlivetoDie that is what the mistake previous developer did.. I have no option now. It has thousands of records

Comment: this will be helpful for you:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080410/4248328

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert  your varchar column as a date

```
  select str_to_date(your_col, '%d/%m/%Y') my_date
  from your_table  
  order by my_date ASC


  $this->db->select(' paid_amount,  discount_allowed,  str_to_date(your_col, '%d/%m/%Y') as my_date');
  $this->db->order_by('my_date','ASC');
```

Comment: This the query coming SELECT str_to_date(order_date, `'%d/%m/%Y')` as my_date FROM (`due`) ORDER BY `my_date` ASC

Comment: I have updated my PHP code in the question.. can you check and tell the error I am making in query and fetching the date there?

Comment: you are not selecting any of the column you try to echo  .. you are just select the my_date  ..  .. you are changing question each steps this is not right and is not fair   ..this is not a coding service .. if you have not error mean the my suggestion  work ... but the code you need is your problem  . and is not related  to this question  .

Comment: could be you need  to add the column need  you really need  .. i have a pair for suggestion  ..  answer  updated with  column paid_amount,  discount_allowed added

Answer (score 0):

You can try using STR_TO_DATE of MySQL

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y') as newcolumnname
FROM    yourtable order by newcolumnname asc
```

Comment: how to do this in code ignitor? I have given a sample in question

Comment: Add the column in your `SELECT` clause?